# How can I prevent variable injection in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, code-injection

I was triggered again on a comment on a recent PowerShell question from @Ansgar Wiechers: [`DO NOT use Invoke-Expression`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) with regards to a security question I have for a long time somewhere in the back of my mind and need to ask.

The strong statement (with a reference to the [Invoke-Expression considered harmful](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) article) suggests that an invocation of a script that can overwrite variables is considered harmful.

Also the [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer) advises against using `Invoke-Expression`, see the [AvoidUsingInvokeExpression rule](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/master/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingInvokeExpression.md).

But I once used a technic myself to update a common variable in a recursive script which can actually overwrite a value in any of its parents scopes which is as simple as:

```
([Ref]$ParentVariable).Value = $NewValue
```

As far as I can determine a potential malicious script could use this technic too to inject variables in any case no matter how it is invoked...

Consider the following "malicious" `Inject.ps1` script:

```
([Ref]$MyValue).Value = 456
([Ref]$MyString).Value = 'Injected string'
([Ref]$MyObject).Value = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Injected'; Value = 'Object'}
```

My `Test.ps1` script:

```
$MyValue = 123
$MyString = "MyString"
$MyObject = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'My'; Value = 'Object'}
.\Inject.ps1
Write-Host $MyValue
Write-Host $MyString
Write-Host $MyObject
```

Result:

```
456
Injected string
@{Name=Injected; Value=Object}
```

As you see all three variables in the `Test.ps1` scope are overwritten by the `Inject.ps1` script. This can also be done using the Invoke-Command cmdlet and it doesn't even matter whether I set the scope of a variable to `Private` either:

```
New-Variable -Name MyValue -Value 123 -Scope Private
$MyString = "MyString"
$MyObject = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'My'; Value = 'Object'}
Invoke-Command {
    ([Ref]$MyValue).Value = 456
    ([Ref]$MyString).Value = 'Injected string'
    ([Ref]$MyObject).Value = [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Injected'; Value = 'Object'}
}
Write-Host $MyValue
Write-Host $MyString
Write-Host $MyObject
```

Is there a way to completely isolate an invoked script/command from overwriting variables in the current scope?
If not, can this be considered as a security risk for invoking scripts in any way?

Comment: @BoogaRoo: It's not just about _variables_, it's about generally preventing unintended manipulation by untrusted code, which could affect functions and aliases too. Even for variables it would be impractical to create all your variables with `$private:` just to guard against potential manipulation. Also, other, trusted code may rely on variables _not_ being private. As for `Invoke-Command`: unfortunately, the docs are incorrect: _by default_, local invocation happens in a _child scope_, but you can opt into same-scope execution with `-NoNewScope`.

Comment: @BoogaRoo Fortunately, the docs have since been corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advice against use of `Invoke-Expression` use is primarily about preventing *unintended* execution of code (code injection).

If you invoke a piece of PowerShell code - whether directly or via `Invoke-Expression` - it can indeed (possibly maliciously) manipulate parent scopes, including the global scope.
Note that this potential manipulation isn't limited to *variables*: for instance, *functions* and *aliases* can be modified as well.

**Caveat**: **Running unknown code is problematic** in two respects:

- Primarily for the potential **to perform unwanted / destructive actions *directly***.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Secondarily, for the potential to **maliciously modify the caller's *state*** (variables, ...), which is **the *only* aspect  the solutions below guard against**.

To provide the **desired isolation**, you have two basic choices:

- Run the code in a ***child* process**:

  - By starting another PowerShell instance; e.g. (use `powershell` instead of `pwsh` in Windows PowerShell):

    - `pwsh -c { ./someUntrustedScript.ps1 }`
  - By starting a *background job*; e.g.:

    - `Start-Job { ./someUntrustedScript.ps1 } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove`
- Run the code in a **separate *thread*** in the same process:

  - As a *thread job*, via the `Start-ThreadJob` cmdlet (ships with PowerShell [Core] 6+; in Windows PowerShell, it can be installed [from the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob) with something like 
    `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser ThreadJob`); e.g.:

    - `Start-ThreadJob { ./someUntrustedScript.ps1 } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemove`
  - By creating a *new runspace* via the PowerShell SDK; e.g.:

    - `[powershell]::Create().AddScript('./someUntrustedScript.ps1').Invoke()`
    - Note that you'll have to do extra work to get the output streams *other* than the success one, notably the error stream's output; also, `.Dispose()` should be called on the PowerShell instance on completion of the command.

A *child process*-based solution will be slow and limited in terms of data types you can return (due to serialization / deserialization being involved), but it provides isolation against the invoked code crashing the process.

A thread-based job is much faster, can return any data type, but can crash the entire process.

In all cases you will have to pass any values from the caller that the invoked code needs access to as *arguments* or, with background jobs and thread jobs, alternatively via the `$using:` scope specifier.

---

[js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6654942/js2010) mentions other, less desirable alternatives:

- `Start-Process` (child process-based, with text-only arguments and output)
- [PowerShell Workflows](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/26/powershell-workflows-the-basics.aspx), which are obsolescent (they weren't ported to PowerShell *Core* and won't be).
- Using `Invoke-Command` with "loopback remoting" (`-ComputerName localhost`) is hypothetically also an option, but then you incur the double overhead of a child process and HTTP-based communication; also, your computer must be set up for remoting, and you must run with elevation (as administrator).

---

<sup>[1] A way to *mitigate* the problem is to *limit which commands, statements, types, ... are permitted to be called* when the string is evaluated, which can be achieved via the [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/windows-powershel) in combination with [language modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Language_Modes)and/or by explicitly constructing an [initial session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806919/45375) for an example of SDK use with language modes.</sup>

Comment: Hmm, a kludgy way to get the output from start-process.  `start-process -wait -nonewwindow powershell 'ps | Export-Clixml out.xml'; import-clixml out.xml`

Comment: @js2010 It's perhaps cleaner to combine `-RedirectStandardOutput out.xml` with the CLI's `-of XML` parameter; overall, however, this is merely a more cumbersome alternative to `Start-Job` that is additionally limited to passing input as text (except if you provide input as CLIXML via stdin and `-if XML`).

Comment: Thanks for the update, the `Start-Thread` was exactly where I wanted to get your attention (by upvoting the answer) as I found out that it now indeed a part of PowerShell core. The point that I am actually investigating is fact that it helps to prevent **variable** injection (where I asked for) but not to general **code** injection, see [Malicious code injection protection #12377](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12377)

Comment: Yes, `Start-ThreadJob` comes with PowerShell [Core] 6+ (I've updated the answer to make that clearer). I'll take a look at the GitHub issue.

Comment: @iRon, I've also added a note to the answer to make it clear that the isolation techniques presented there only guard against manipulation of the caller's state, but not generally against execution of unwanted commands.