# Does Invoke-Command run in the current scope, or a child scope, when run locally?

Tags: powershell, scope

I was informed in a [comment on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985269/how-can-i-prevent-variable-injection-in-powershell) that:

> As for `Invoke-Command`: unfortunately, the docs are incorrect: by
>   default, local invocation happens in a child scope, but you can opt
>   into same-scope execution with `-NoNewScope`. – mklement0

However, according to the [help documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-5.1#description)(emphasis added):

> You can also use Invoke-Command on a local computer to evaluate or run
>   a string in a script block as a command. Windows PowerShell converts
>   the script block to a command and runs the command immediately **in the
>   current scope**, instead of just echoing the string at the command line.

This appears to work as expected:

```
PS C:\> $TestVar = 99
PS C:\> Invoke-Command { Get-Variable TestVar }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
TestVar                        99
```

If the documentation was wrong, I would expect that to cause the variable to be unavailable to the `Invoke-Command`. Is the documentation correct after all?

Comment: Look at it this way. The 2nd $a is unchanged :  `invoke-command { $a = 1 } ; $a`

Comment: @js2010 I like that. It's a very succinct way to show the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation gives mixed information and the quoted section in the question is definitely outdated/incorrect.

The section of help that gives the correct info is under `-NoNewScope` which states:

> Indicates that this cmdlet runs the specified command in the current
>   scope. By default, Invoke-Command runs commands in their own scope.
>
> This parameter is valid only in commands that are run in the current
>   session, that is, commands that omit both the ComputerName and Session
>   parameters.
>
> This parameter was introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.

The following shows the scope information from `-NoNewScope` is correct(demonstrated with numbered scopes):

```
$TestVar = 99
Invoke-Command { Get-Variable TestVar -Scope 0 } #Scope 0, current scope
Invoke-Command { Get-Variable TestVar -Scope 1 } #Scope 1, parent scope
Invoke-Command { Get-Variable TestVar -Scope 0 } -NoNewScope #Scope 0, current scope
```

Results from the first command will return an error saying the variable can't be found:

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Command { Get-Variable TestVar -Scope 0 } #Scope 0, current scope
Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with the name 'TestVar'.
```

The other commands will return the variable information as expected. However, as mentioned in the comment on the other post, `-NoNewScope` has to be used to explicitly tell `Invoke-Command` to use the current scope or else it will run in a child scope by default.

The only reason the command in the question worked is because variables are available to child scopes by default and no scope needed to be declared since neither the `-ComputerName` or `-Session` parameter were used.

As of 8/21/2019, the [documentation update request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/4548) has been completed. The new version of the problematic section mentioned in the question now reads:

```
You can also use `Invoke-Command` on a local computer to a script block as a command.
PowerShell runs the script block immediately in a child scope of the current scope.
```