# Converting string with object layout to object

Tags: powershell

Some objects has been saved to a txt.file
looking like this:

```
@{flightNumber=01; flightDate=2010-01-10; flightIdentification=201001}
@{flightNumber=01; flightDate=2010-01-10; flightIdentification=201002}
```

and I'm trying to read them in another program and convert them back into objects. What bothers me is that it understands each of the "objects" as a string and I have been unable to cast it into an object.

```
$list = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\XXXXX\Downloads\TemplateObject.txt'
foreach (@object in $list) {
    Write-Host $object.flightNumber
}
```

From what I've shown, I would expect to see 2 different objects with the variables flightNumber, flightDate and flightIdentification

1. I've tried piping it by using ConvertFrom-StringData
2. I've tried casting to an object

I expect 2 separate objects containing 3 variables in each.

Comment: PowerShell can't read the format it uses to display objects back as objects (the format lacks too much detail for that). If you want to export objects in a way that can be read back later, use `Export-CliXml` (for full fidelity) or `ConvertTo-Json` (if you want something that other tools can manipulate).

Comment: As @JeroenMostert says, using a format designed for this situation is the way to go, but if you have no control over that, then one thing you could do is use [Invoke-Expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6).  For example, replace `write-host $object.flightNumber` with `(Invoke-Expression $object).flightNumber`.  However, use only as a very last resort as this technique [can be dangerous](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingInvokeExpression.md).

Comment: The danger from unfiltered input aside, `Invoke-Expression` will turn `@{flightNumber=01; flightDate=2010-01-10; flightIdentification=201001}` into an object where `flightDate` has the value `1999` (because that's 2010 - 1 - 10), which is worse than not working. The output format explicitly does not roundtrip.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, good catch.  Yeah, `Invoke-Expression` is even worse than I feared :-(

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for the answer! I'll work with your solution :)

Comment: As concluded above, the expression above doesn't roundtrip because it isn't correctly converted to a PowerShell Expression in the first place. Properties that represent a string should be quoted, like: `...; flightDate='2010-01-10';...`. For a complete roundtrip, try: `,$Object |` [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) `| Invoke-Expression <=> $Object` (see also: [How can I prevent variable injection in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56985269/1701026))

Answer (score 1):

### Don't pipe objects directly to files!

As [has been pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037769/converting-string-with-object-layout-to-object/57038387#comment100603553_57037769), take advantage of built-in options for serialization to disk, like `ConvertTo-Csv`/`Export-Csv` for flat objects, `ConvertTo-Json` or `Export-Clixml` for more complex objects.

---

As a one-off thing, if you need to recover and re-encode this data, you could use the regex `-replace` operator to add quotes around the values, at which point the parser should accept them as hashtable entries and you can cast it to an object:

```
$string = '@{flightNumber=01; flightDate=2010-01-10; flightIdentification=201001}'

# Place double-quotes around anything found between a `=` and `;` or `}`
$quotedString = $string -replace '(?<=\=)([^=;}]+)(?=\s*(?:;|}))', '"$1"'

# Parse the resulting string as if it was PowerShell code
$errors = @()
$objectAST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($quotedString, [ref]$null,[ref]$errors)
$objects = if(-not $errors){
    # This is pretty dangerous, you should NEVER do this in a production script
    $objectAST.GetScriptBlock.Invoke() |ForEach-Object {
        [pscustomobject]$_
    }
}

# This variable now contains the re-animated objects
$objects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string to a hashtable using convertfrom-stringdata after some manipulation:

```
$a = '@{flightNumber=01; flightDate=2010-01-10; flightIdentification=201001}'
$a = $a -replace '@{' -replace '}' -replace ';',"`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData
[pscustomobject]$a

flightNumber flightIdentification flightDate
------------ -------------------- ----------
01           201001               2010-01-10
```