# PowerShell Ast for injection detection

Tags: powershell, abstract-syntax-tree, code-injection

I am generating a ScriptBlock based on DB input which I invoke later in the script. I now want to ensure that a malicious user is not injecting any PS code in the DB varchar field that then gets executed.

First, I filtered the String Script Block for forbidden chars such as $ or ;. But I want to take it one step further and use AST to check if there is any executable code in the DB field.

When I use $Ast.FindAll for a specific element such as ForEachStatementAst it works fine.
However, I also want to be able to detect cmdlets etc in the String.
Examples that should be recognised as being ok:

- abc
- 123
- 'a','b'
- true

Examples that should be recognised as being not ok:

- Write-host or Remove-Item or any other get-command cmdlet.
- `$(MySubExpression)

When using AST visualisation, I get the same tree for both examples. ('abc', 'Write-Host')

ScriptBlockAst-> NamedBlockAst -> PipelineAst -> CommandAst -> StringConstantExpressionAst

Is there any way I can use AST to determine whether the DB field (or any string) contains only allowed entries such as non PS keywords / cmdlets, numbers etc but nothing that could be used as a PS command and that could be invoked?

The following code works for the test cases but I wonder if this can be achieved in a better way. If Res.count > 0, the input was not ok, if =0, it was ok.

```
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
[System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]]$InputStringList = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]"
$InputStringList.Add("foreach (`$x in @('a','b')){;}")
$InputStringList.Add("New-item -Path 'C:\Test.txt' -ItemType File")
$InputStringList.Add("Write-host 'as'")
$InputStringList.Add("abc")
$InputStringList.Add("a,b,c")
$InputStringList.Add("123")
$InputStringList.Add("true")
[System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Type]]$TypeList = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Type]"
$TypeList.Add([System.Management.Automation.Language.StringLiteralToken])
$TypeList.Add([System.Management.Automation.Language.ScriptBlockAst])
$TypeList.Add([System.Management.Automation.Language.NamedBlockAst])
$TypeList.Add([System.Management.Automation.Language.StringConstantExpressionAst])
$TypeList.Add([System.Management.Automation.Language.ConstantExpressionAst])
$TypeList.Add([System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandExpressionAst])
$TypeList.Add([System.Management.Automation.Language.CommandAst])
$TypeList.Add([System.Management.Automation.Language.PipelineAst])
$TypeList.Add([System.Management.Automation.Language.ArrayLiteralAst])
[String[]]$CommandArray = (Get-Command | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name')
[System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]$Predicate =
{
    param([System.Management.Automation.Language.Ast]$AstObject)
    Write-Debug -Message $AstObject.GetType().FullName
    if($AstObject -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.StringConstantExpressionAst])
    {
        if($AstObject.Value -in $CommandArray)
        {
            return $true
        }
        else
        {
            return $false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return (-not($AstObject.GetType() -in $TypeList))
    }
}
$InputStringList.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object -Process `
{
    Write-Debug -Message ("Processing string: "+$PsItem.ToString())
    $ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($PsItem, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)
    $res=$ast.FindAll($Predicate, $true)
    Write-Debug -Message $res.count.ToString()
}
```

Comment: "I am generating a ScriptBlock based on DB input" - _why_? If the scriptblocks are not supposed to contain command invocations, are you really sure you need a scriptblock then?

Comment: The overall scriptblock contains command invocations which I add in my PS. But the DB field is used only for Int, String values that should not contain any invocable code.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest passing the DB values as arguments to the scriptblock(s) instead

Comment: in my case I am generating a M365 DSC configuration. So I do not know how many DSC Resources I will get and which Attribute / Value pairs I will have as this all depends on the DB and the resulting DataView object I get. I am then generating a string that is the dsc configuration, create a new ScriptBlock for that string and then . source the script block to create the MOF file.

Comment: You might want to check out [scriptblock.checkrestrictedlanguage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.checkrestrictedlanguage?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)

Comment: What you trying to do is creating your own restricted [languagemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes). It would probably be easier to invoke the scriptblock in an restricted runspace, see e.g.: [Automatically retrieve Allowed Types for Constrained Language mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806919/1701026)

Comment: See: [`#13699` Feature Request: Import-PowershellDataFile should accept string input](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13699)

Comment: @Chris It'd be very helpful if you could provide a sample set of input values and the resulting DSC configuration file you expect - we can probably help you write some better (and safer) templating code for it, but it's hard to know where to start without knowing the goal :)

Comment: Input would be as defined in the M365DSC wiki on GitHub. I retrieve a dataView object containing the cols 'AttributeKey','AttributeValue' as VARCHARs. One example would be the TeamsMeetingConfiguration https://github.com/microsoft/Microsoft365DSC/wiki/TeamsMeetingConfiguration . In my PS, I define the configuration as a string and then insert the key value pairs based on the DataView content. For example. ClientAppSharingPort = 50040 whereas ClientAppSharingPort would be the AttributeKey in the DB and 50040 would be the AttributeValue. The solution must allow the DSC config to compile to a MOF

Answer (score 1):

As commented, what you trying to do is creating your own restricted [languagemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes). Meaning that it would probably be easier to invoke the concerned scriptblock in an restricted runspace.
Derived from [**@mklement0**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) great answer for [Automatically retrieve Allowed Types for Constrained Language mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806919/1701026):

```
Function Invoke-Restricted {
    [CmdletBinding()]param([String]$Expression)
    $Restricted = [powershell]::Create()
    $Restricted.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.LanguageMode = 'Restricted'
    Try { $Restricted.AddScript($expression).Invoke() }
    Catch { $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_) }
}
```

**Restricted expression**

```
Invoke-Restricted @'
    @{
        string    = 'abc'
        int       = 123
        array     = 'a','b'
        hashtable = @{ a = 1; b = 2 }
        boolean   = $true
    }
'@
```

Yields

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
array                          {a, b}
int                            123
boolean                        True
string                         abc
hashtable                      {b, a}
```

**Invalid expression**

```
Invoke-Restricted @'
    @{
        TimeSpan = [TimeSpan]'12:34:45'
    }
'@
```

Throws an error:

```
Invoke-Restricted: Exception calling "Invoke" with "0" argument(s): "At line:1 char:1
+ [TimeSpan]"12:34:45"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
The type TimeSpan is not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section."
```

Yet, it has some limitations as it does not prevent e.g. the use of cmdlets.

For an easy and secure way to retrieve a (structured) configuration file I would depend on a serialized format as [`JSON`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) using the [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) cmdlet

Related: [`#12377` Running partly trusted PowerShell code in a restricted security environment.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12377)

Comment: This is clever, but it won't work - PowerShell will (for good reason) refuse to parse the configuration block in restricted language mode